# How to sort integers in a list of lists but via skipping a particular index of each list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list of lists with 3 integers like this :

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[2,4,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,4],[5,4,3],[4,3,2],[5,4,3], [3,4,2]]
```

I want to delete the list if it has a symmetrical in myList. For ex. `[1,2,3]` and `[3,2,1]` is symmetrical and either `[1,2,3]` or `[3,2,1]` can stay in the new list but not both.

I tried sorting to get rid of symmetric lists

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[2,4,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,4],[5,4,3],[4,3,2],[5,4,3], [3,4,2]]
result = set()

for elem in myList: 
    result.add(tuple(sorted(elem)))

result = list(result)
print(result)
```

Code resulted as:

```
[(3, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Although I did get rid of symmetrical lists, I want to keep the position of every number at the middle **unchanged** and just sort each list in increasing/decreasing order only by considering their first and third integers.

For ex. [2,**4**,3],[3,**2**,4],[3,**4**,2] should be sorted as -> [2,**4**,3],[3,**2**,4],[2,**4**,3] and then I could get rid of identicals -> [2,4,3],[3,2,4]

Could you please suggest me a way to sort integers in the lists in myList but via skipping the middle value of each list like below so that I could eliminate the symmetrical lists?

Comment: Is `[3, 1, 2]` also symmetrical with `[1, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: No, it isn't. What I mean by symmetrical is like [x,y,z] and [z,y,x].

Comment: Also, Only one element should remain in the original list according to selection criteria

Answer (score 0):

From

```
[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[3,1,2],[2,1,3],[1,3,2],[2,3,1]]
```

we keep

```
[[1,2,3],        [3,1,2],        [1,3,2]]
```

because the middle element is fix and the 1st/3rd are equal in the removed ones.

We accomplis this by creating tuples consisiting of your middle element and the set of all numbers - we keep the first of each, the others we trash - all without reordering the original elements at all:

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[2,4,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,4],[5,4,3],[4,3,2],[5,4,3], [3,4,2]]

# create a set of sets to keep
mySets = set((p[1],frozenset(p)) for p in myList)

rv = []

# go through your list
for nums in myList:
    # create a set from the current item in your list
    fs = (nums[1], frozenset(nums))
    # if we want to keep it, do so
    if fs in mySets:
        rv.append(nums)
        # and remove it from the to be kept list
        mySets.remove(fs)
    # if empty, we are done
    if not mySets:
        break 
print(rv)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 4], [5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Removes symmetry.
removed_symmetry = list(filter(lambda obj: tuple(obj) not in [tuple(x) for x in [i for i in myList if i is not obj]], myList))

# Sorts based on left and right value.
middle_unchanged_sort = [[x, y, z] if x < z else [z, y, x] for x, y, z in myList]
```

Not sure I fully understood exactly what you are asking, but the above two will do seperate functionalities to `myList`.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `set` of unique `lists` from `myList`. See the ***last section header*** for sorting the way you asked for.

### A Set of Unique Tuples

If obtaining the final result as a set of tuples works then you could it as follows.

```py
set([tuple(sorted(e)) for e in myList])
# Or using map
set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), myList))
```

**Output**:

```
{(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5)}
```

### A List of Unique Lists

If you must have your final result as a list of unique lists, then you could try this.

```py
[list(ee) for ee in set([tuple(sorted(e)) for e in myList])]
# Or using map
list(map(list, set([tuple(sorted(e)) for e in myList])))
```

**Output**:

```
[[3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

### Extracting Non-Duplicates/Non-Mirrored Lists

You could use `pandas` library to do this as well.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# use pandas.DataFrame to sort by 
# first and third values in each row
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(myList), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda row: '{}-{}-{}'.format(row.A+row.C, row.B, row.C+row.A), axis=1)

df = (df
        .sort_values(['D', 'A', 'C'], ascending=True, inplace=False)
        .drop_duplicates(subset=['D'], keep='first', inplace=False, ignore_index=False)
        .drop(columns=['D'], inplace=False)
    )
#print(df)

# make list of lists sorted by 
# first and third values in each list
# And drop the duplicates (mirrored)
[list(e) for e in df.to_numpy()]
# Or
list(map(list, df.to_numpy()))
```

**Output**:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], [2, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 4], [5, 4, 3]]
```

If you want the answer in the same order as in the original `myList`, you could do the following:

```py
# after running what was done previously to df
[list(e) for e in df.sort_index().to_numpy()]
# Or
list(map(list, df.sort_index().to_numpy()))
```

**Output**:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 3], [2, 1, 3], [3, 2, 4], [5, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
myList = [[1,2,3],[2,4,3],[2,1,3],[3,2,4],[5,4,3],[4,3,2],[5,4,3], [3,4,2]]
result = set()
for elem in myList:
    # Check if reversed tuple is in the set 
    if tuple(reversed(elem)) not in result:
        # Add it to the set if not
        result.add(tuple(elem))

# Map the tuple set to lists of list
result = list(map(list, result))

print(result)
```

Gives the result:

```
[[2, 4, 3], [4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 3], [3, 2, 4], [2, 1, 3]]
```